# Using PHP CURL to login to a remote web site

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to login to a remote web site using CURL, but can't seem to get it to work.

The page I'm trying to login to is: https://vp1-voiceportal.megapath.com/Login/

So far, I've tried the following:

```
$username="username"; 
$password="password"; 
$url="https://vp1-voiceportal.megapath.com/Login/servlet/com.broadsoft.clients.oam.servlets.Login"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 

$postdata = "EnteredUserID=".$username."&password=".$password."&domain=&UserID=&rememberPass="; 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 

echo $result;  
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I get the following response, which reroutes me to the login page:

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://vp1-voiceportal.megapath.com/Error/pageError.jsp?code=404">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at vp1-voiceportal.megapath.com Port 443</address>
</body></html>

Comment: 1. How did you get your cookie file? Maybe cookies expired.
2. What is the result? What did exactly curl return?

Comment: I might be missing something about the cookie file, how should I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: The URL you specified is wrong, it should be:

```
https://vp1-voiceportal.megapath.com/servlet/com.broadsoft.clients.oam.servlets.Login
```

And not:

```
https://vp1-voiceportal.megapath.com/Login/servlet/com.broadsoft.clients.oam.servlets.Login
```

---

It looks like you need to follow redirects and specify the cookie file (for reading), try:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 

echo $result;  

curl_close($ch);
```

It's also a good practice so specify an absolute (and writable) path to the cookie file.

Comment: Thanks, I've made the changes you suggest, but still get the same problem.

Comment: @jeffo: Is the `cookie.txt` file empty? And it exists?

Comment: @jeffo: Also, it seems to me that the URL is wrong... Shouldn't it be `https://vp1-voiceportal.megapath.com/servlet/com.broadsoft.clients.oam.servlets.Login`?

Comment: I tried the URL you suggest, but that didn't work. The cookie file exists and is not empty.

Comment: @jeffo: The URL is clearly wrong, but without having credentials or seeing the response there isn't much more I can do to help you, sorry.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help, I'll plug away at it a bit more. The credentials are for a client, so I can't really pass them on.

Comment: I made some tweaks to the $postdata variable and now it's working. Thanks to @Alix Axel.

Comment: @jeffo: Really? What was the problem? Usually I just pass the array to POSTFIELDS or a string from `http_build_query()`, but unless `$username` or `$password` contain URL characters I don't see any problem in that.