# how to convert ajax json call to jsonp

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I have an ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "www.something.com/login.php",
    cache:false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: { 
        username: $('#user').val(),
        password: $('#pass').val()
           },
        success: function(response) 
        {
           localStorage.setItem('user',response.results[0].user);
           localStorage.setItem('company',response.results[0].company);

        }
});
```

This is not working because I'm trying to connect to the script which is not on the same root as my files, this PHP file is located on the external server.

How do I need to use `JSONP` to get this script working?

Comment: I've tried that and nothing is happening

Comment: You'll have to change what the server actually outputs, as JSONP has to be wrapped in a callback function, otherwise I won't work. In other words, just changing the dataType does nothing.

Comment: I'm creating json object in the php and echo it..can you show me an example?

Comment: That json object will have to be wrapped in a function, as JSONP isn't really ajax, it inserts a script tag into the document, and the wrapping callback function is needed to know when the file has loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can. The only difference between JSON and JSONP is that JSONP is wrapped with a function name;

```
{ "x": "hello" } // JSON
foo({ "x": "hello" }); // JSONP.
```

Comment: How can I change PHP and JS to retrieve data in this form as you said. Here is my PHP for creating json object: `echo json_encode( array(
         "results" => array(
          array(
           "user" => $member['user'],
           "company" => $member['company']
          )
          )
        ));`

Comment: can you please provide me with a solution? Because I can't get this to work

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the information through URL variables.

```
type: "GET",
url: "www.something.com/login.php?login="+username+"&password="+password,
```

Then on the server side:

```
$_GET["username"];
$_GET["password"];
```

But now that I've told you this, **DO NOT DO THIS FOR PASSWORDS AND LOGINS! THIS IS VERY INSECURE!!!**

Instead, create a local PHP file, that shares data with the other website on the backend. If you can't do this, then use `iframes` and use your original method.

Another way is to use cURL. cURL allows you to login just like you were on the page in your browser. It's not very fast, but it works very well on websites you don't have much control over and that don't have an API.

[Using PHP CURL to login to a remote web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394536/using-php-curl-to-login-to-a-remote-web-site)

Comment: So ajax call stays the same and just need to add variables in the url and change post to get?

Comment: @user123_456 - If it's cross domain, as in the page you're trying to connect to has another domain, this answer isn't even close.

Comment: Also change the type to "GET". To do cross domain, the receiving data must be json encoded. Do you have control of the other site?

Comment: If the dataType is changed to JSONP, the method will always be GET, no matter what you type in the `type` property.

Comment: @adeneo this is jquery mobile app deployed as smartphone app, so yes this is cross domain I think. Can you give example?

Comment: No, not really. It's really simple, change the dataType to JSONP and wrap the JSON in a callback function, as shown in the answer by Amith, and as long as it's valid JSONP it should work. An other option would be to set CORS headers on the serverside.

Comment: @adeneo I can't get this to work. can you please provide me with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "www.something.com/login.php",
cache:false,
dataType: "jsonp",
crossDomain: true,
data: { 
    username: $('#user').val(),
    password: $('#pass').val()
       },
    success: function(response) 
    {
       localStorage.setItem('user',response.results[0].user);
       localStorage.setItem('company',response.results[0].company);

    }
});
```

Comment: I get this error in the console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`