# How to log in website (like linkshare) using php curl?

Tags: php, forms, curl, linkshare

the login page is here

https://login.linkshare.com/sso/login

can anyone tell me how to log in this website using php curl.

something special about this website is that the form on the above page has a action url which is a relative path.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you log on in a browser with JavaScript disabled? If so, you just need a browser component that has cookie support. I recommend Goutte, but there are several other approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite simple, almost everything you'll need you can find in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394536/using-php-curl-to-login-to-a-remote-web-site).

Just pay attention to the 2 hidden fields that you need to retrieve first and then append to your request: **lt** and **execution**. There are more hidden fields but their values don't change.